# How to get live streaming permission for LinkedIN

Tags: video, linkedin-api, live-streaming

I want to integrate live video api to my app but i don't know how to get permssion (scope)

here is the document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/live-video/

I create app on linkedin but not able to see those scope/permission
how i can these permssions

r_member_live
w_member_live
etc...

Comment: any luck on this ?

Comment: yes you need to talk to LinkedIn support team, then they will tell you what to do next.